# C++ program returns "valid" result regardless of user input

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to check whether the parentheses are balanced (open and closing). The program runs, but returns `valid` for all user input.

```
#ifndef _STACKLSAB_H_
#define _STACKSLAB_H_

#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "namevaluepair.h"

using namespace std;

class Stacks
{
  public:
    bool balanced(string exp);
    bool match(char open, char closed);
           
  private:
    string st_PostData;
};

#endif
```

stacksLab.cpp (my program works in repl.it but doesn't with cgi):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "stacksLab.h"
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

bool Stacks::match(char open,char closed)
{
    if(open == '(' && closed == ')') return true;
    else if(open == '{' && closed == '}') return true;
    else if(open == '[' && closed == ']') return true;
    return false;
}
bool Stacks::balanced(string exp)
{
    stack<char>  S;

    for(int i = 0;i<exp.length();i++)
    {
        if(exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            S.push(exp[i]);
        else if(exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if(S.empty() || !match(S.top(),exp[i]))
                return false;
            else
                S.pop();
        }
    }
    return S.empty();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stacksLab.h"

#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  /// complete the http header
  cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

  Stacks st;

  string expression;
  cin>>expression;

   if(st.balanced(expression))
        cout<<"Valid\n";
    else
        cout<<"Not Valid\n";

}
```

I think this is the reason my program will not return correctly but not sure which way to go.

```
<form action="runme.cgi" method="POST">

<table align="center" bgcolor="antiquewhite">

<tr>
   <td align="right">Enter parentheses here:</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="parentheses "/> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right"><input type="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Debugging, step one: echo the input in order to verify that it is what you believe it to be.

Comment: Which inputs are giving you "Valid" that should be "Not valid"?

Comment: Also technically identifiers that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter "such as `#ifndef _STACKLSAB_H_` are reserved for the implementation. Unlikely to cause an issue here but generally it is not a good idea to have a potential clash.

Comment: What is contained in `namevaluepair.h` which you did include but didn't provide in the answer? If it's not relevant, then you should reduce the question to the minimum necessary.

Comment: Every input I enter it is giving me a "Valid" response. It should only say "Valid if the parenthesis match. like '(' and ')' but it is giving a "valid" response for just a single '(' and that should response should be "Not valid"

Comment: Again, echo your input. Add `cout << "Input: " << expression << '\n';` immediately after reading it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies not with your stack processing (I gave your code some rudimentary tests, and it seems to work) but, rather, with the way your are taking input.

The `cin << expression;` line will read characters from your input **up to but not including** the first whitespace (i.e. a newline **or** a space character). Thus, if you enter the string, `abc (((}}}` (which, clearly, has unbalanced brackets), then your program will show `valid` because the string it is testing is just the `abc` part.

To fix this, use the [`std::getline` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), instead, which reads up to the first occurrence of a *given* delimiter character (which, by default, is the newline).

The following `main` works with the rest of your code unchanged, judging from the (admittedly, limited) tests I have run:

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
    Stacks st;
    string expression;
    getline(cin, expression, '\n'); // The '\n' argument can be omitted, as this is the default

    if (st.balanced(expression))
        cout << "Valid\n";
    else
        cout << "Not Valid\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As an additional 'suggested improvement', you should perhaps change the `int i` loop-index in your `balanced` function to a `size_t` type - which is actually the type required for operands to the `[]` operator of Standard Library container objects (like `std::string` and `std::vector`):

```cpp
bool Stacks::balanced(string exp)
{
    stack<char>  S;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) { // size_t is more precise than int
        //... and so forth
```

Comment: given the input appears to be html, he may also want to just read the entire stream into `expression`, but I don't know an easy way to do that

Comment: @MooingDuck If that's the case (I'll await clarity from OP) then we could just set `expression` empty and, in a `while` loop keep reading into another string and concatenating that to `expression` until the stream is depleted.